# Is immigration causing unemployment among low-skill workers in the UK?

Tags: europe, immigration, unemployment

Immigration policy is a hot topic in UK politics, but is it actually costing British jobs?

Comment: Please add something to show that this is a widely held belief that people should be skeptical of.

Comment: Well that is practically unavoidable if you believe the figures published by the Daily Mail ('Daily Fail'?) this november 2013: *14.6, 9.5, 4.6 and 4.2 million immigrants from India, Pakistan, Nigeria and the Philippines got a UK citizenship in 2012*. It turns out these numbers were the **percentages** of British citizenships granted across these countries ;-), from a total of 194,900 people. (Could not find the original error any more, only the corrected figures http://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/pa/article-2840260/More-migrants-given-UK-citizenship.html)

Comment: @LarianLeQuella it's a very notable claim of parties like UKIP--but I'm sure that many similar claims are made about Mexicans in the US, for example.

Comment: @JanDoggen Wow, confusing percentages with millions is a fail even by Daily Mail standards.

Comment: @Sklivvz - you are correct. I'm too lazy to search ATM but I saw tons of such claims for USA.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the British have such a big problem with unskilled migrants as they like to think.

This report highlights the trends in the UK low-skilled job market from the 80s/90s to 2013:

[Migrants in low-skilled work

Migration Advisory Committee

Full Report
July 2014](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/333083/MAC-Migrants_in_low-skilled_work__Full_report_2014.pdf)

It seems to suggest that migration patterns are consistent across the skill spectrum and that migrants have not significantly or unfairly displaced UK born workers.

Here is a selection from chapters 3 ("Recent migration to the UK and factors affecting this") and 4 ("Employment in low-skilled work"):

> 3.4 Migrants accounted for approximately 16 per cent of all low-skilled employment aged 16-64 in the UK, slightly above the
>   overall share of the population but broadly in line with their share
>   of all employed persons, regardless of skill level.
>
> 3.8 One million migrants in low-skilled work in 2013 have come to the UK within the last ten years. Half of these came from Central and
>   Eastern Europe, following EU enlargement in 2004 and 2007. Over
>   300,000 came from Poland, who account for around one in six of all
>   migrant workers in low-skilled employment and almost one in three of
>   those who arrived since 2004. Even so, by 2013 migrants from Central
>   and Eastern Europe still accounted for little more than a quarter of
>   all foreign born workers in low-skilled occupations.
>
> 4.4 We also considered the ‘hollowing out’ of the labour market and while the evidence is not definitive, there have clearly been
>   substantial changes in the type of jobs available. This has important
>   implications for the composition of the labour force by gender and
>   progression up the skill ladder.
>
> 4.5 While the overall UK employment rate has been stable since 2000, there have been important shifts by gender and age. The employment of
>   UK-born aged 50 to 64 has increased, while the employment of other
>   UK-born groups has declined. These changes in employment correspond to
>   changes in population, with the exceptions of the 50 to 64 age group,
>   for whom employment has increased more than the growth in population,
>   and the under 25 age group, for whom population increased but both
>   employment and participation fell.
>
> 4.6 It might be thought that the decline in employment for the under 25 age group is associated with greater competition with migrants for
>   low-skilled jobs. While this is possible we note that the youth
>   unemployment rate is comparable to 30 years ago when there was far
>   less migration. There are other factors to consider as well, such as
>   the increase in the number of 16 to 24 year olds choosing to stay in
>   education, which therefore affects the number that will be in work and
>   participating in the labour force.
>
> 4.21 The decline in low skilled employment among the UK-born was more than offset by a 2 million increase in high skilled working.
>   High-skilled employment among migrants also expanded considerably from
>   1 million in 1997 to 2.3 million by 2013.
>
> 4.54 In contrast to the older age group, while employment of men and women aged under 25 has decreased, their population has increased.
>   This results in large decreases in their employment rates of 14
>   percentage points for men aged under 25 and nine percentage points for
>   women aged under 25. We explore reasons for these changes, such as
>   greater participation in tertiary education, just below in section
>   4.6.
>
> 4.55 Overall, between 1997 and 2013 the employment rate for the 16 to 64 UK- born population has increased by half a percentage point and
>   this would have been affected by the recession post-2008. Changes in
>   population and participation rates by gender and age have been largely
>   offsetting such that overall the UK-born employment rate appears to
>   have been relatively unaffected during the period of significant and
>   rapid migration to the UK. However, although the overall measure has
>   hardly changed, there have been some important shifts by gender and
>   age, where employment has increased for some groups and decreased for
>   others.
>
> 4.63 It is possible that a contributing factor to the changes in youth unemployment and NEET rates is the increase in migration to the UK
>   during the mid-2000s. This is particularly relevant for low-skilled
>   employment, since as Office for National Statistics (2014k) points
>   out, young people are more likely to work in the lowest skilled jobs,
>   particularly elementary occupations and sales and customer service
>   occupations. Young people could, therefore, experience greater
>   competition for such jobs, due to the increase in migrants also
>   looking for work in these areas.
>
> 4.64 However, at national level the youth unemployment rate has been at similar levels before, during a time of much lower migration. The
>   unemployment rate for 16 to 24 year olds was the same in 1984 as it
>   was in 2013 (Office for National Statistics (2014k)). In fact, the
>   proportion of the total population of 16 to 24 year olds who are
>   unemployed is lower in 2013 than it was in 1984, 13 per cent compared
>   to 15 per cent.
>
> 4.86 Many 16 to 24 year olds will not want to pursue further academic study. It is important for this group that they are able to gain
>   requisite skills through vocational education and work experience.
>   Wolf (2011)’s comprehensive review of vocational education in England
>   “found conclusive evidence of serious problems in current provision:
>   problems which impact directly on young people and their futures,” and
>   came to the damning conclusion that “too many of our young people are
>   being short-changed.”
>
> 4.110 It might be considered that the decline in employment for the under 25 age group is primarily due to greater competition with
>   migrants for low-skilled jobs. While this is possible we note that the
>   youth unemployment rate is comparable to 30 years ago when there was
>   far less migration and that the state of the economy and level of
>   demand play important roles in labour market outcomes for 16 to 24
>   year olds. In addition, academic attainment, work experience and soft
>   skills all play a role in determining a young person’s access to
>   employment and training opportunities. Basic qualifications,
>   especially English and mathematics, are incredibly important for their
>   employment prospects. There is evidence to suggest that the skills of
>   young people in these areas are placing them at a disadvantage in
>   today’s labour market.

Comment: Could you spell it out a bit more? I'n not sure how this report shows whether "immigration is causing unemployment" (the question), nor even that "the British may not have such a big problem as they like to think" (your counter-claim).

Comment: Your answer's data contradicts your claim. ` Migrants accounted for approximately 16 per cent of all low-skilled employment aged 16-64 in the UK,` - that means UK unemployment is significantly impacted among that demographics, to the tune of up to 16% (you also have added complications of unemployment figures NOT counting those who gave up looking for work, partially because they realize immigrants undercut them on price)